# Android - Simple AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, lifecycle

Hi I have a question about Android AsyncTask.
I have a fragment within an Activity.
That fragment calls AsyncTask where it does something heavy and update the UI in the onPostExecute().
My question is this. LEt's say the user opened the Activity.
Now the fragment is attached and AsyncTask's doInBackground() is called.
Then the user suddenly presses back button to close the activity.
Now, what happens to the execution in the AsyncTask thread?
Does thread also die as soon as the activity is closed?
Or do I have manually check in onPostExecute whether this Fragment is still attached by using isAdded() at the beginning of onostExecute()?
Thanks!

EDIT

In my Fragment, I declare AsyncTask() implicitly.. like this

```
            new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                    return processPlays(plays);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                    if (!isAdded()) return; // IS THIS FINE?
                    // UPDATE UI
                }
            }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads run until they either finish or until Android system dumps the memory.  Your AsyncTask will keep running, so you need to do the check if you can't outright cancel it.  Else you'll get these situations where your app will crash without you even seeing it open.

Likewise, Fragments can be detached and destroyed during the lifecycle of an app. You can never assume that a Fragment or Activity is still active once returned from an AsyncTask's doInBackground()

Comment: Yea.. that's why I have if(!isAdded()) return; at the beginning of onPostExecute(); See the attached code. Is this safe?

Comment: Yes.  That is safe. 

Note.  "isAdded" doesn't necessarily mean that the Fragment doesn't exist or won't be added later, so it is still recommended to save the State regardless and update the UI if needed.

Answer (score 0):

On that case the `AsyncTask` thread will keep running until the end, and if unchecked may crash inside `onPostExecute()`. Most of the times you'll want to cancel the `AsyncTask` on the `onStop()`, `onFinish()` or even `onPause()` of the `Activity` (depending on your application).

You can cancel a Task with the `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` method. From the [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after
>   doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: The thing is that my AsyncTask is declared implicitly..

like new AsyncTask<..>{ ... }.execute();

And I run if(!isAdded()) return; at the beginning of onPostExecute(). Is this safe?

Comment: You still can save a reference for the AsyncTask in a class field. `asyncTask = new AsyncTask<..>{ ... }; asyncTask.execute();` Then it's possible to call `asyncTask.cancel()` anywhere you want. What you've done it's safe, maybe just not what it's recommended.